# Intellij IDEA Run configuration System Environment don't match OS env

Tags: intellij-idea

I've created new run configuration for my project in Intellij and I have some problems executing it as it is expected to rely on environment variables in order to run my jar correctly.

When I'm checking `Environment Variables` configuration the `Include parent environment variables` is checked and when I click `show` to see `System Environment` I noticed that my `PATH` variable don't match the `PATH` variable from my user and system variables on OS.

I'm running on Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit and Intellij IDEA version is 2018.3.4 Ultimate Edition (Build #IU-183.5429.30). Could someone point on where to look at? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference in `PATH` in IntelliJ IDEA and Windows? Does IDE miss any directories defined in system `PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The thing is that I was starting IDEA instance with the help of Jetbrains Toolbox app. When started it directly from the `...JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA\ch-0\183.5429.30\bin\idea64.exe` the Environment Variables matched the OS configuration.

I'm not sure what Toolbox does but it changes execution environment of the IDEA causing it to see different OS Environment Variables.

Comment: If someone knows how to solve problem using toolbox start please post the answer.